# "su user" does not work on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, su

I have a new CentOS server.

This is server `uname` info:

[image: unmae info]

```
[root@server ~]# uname -vr
3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 26 15:12:11 UTC 2018
[root@server ~]#
```

When I try to change user using the `su` command, nothing happens after running the command:

[image: su result]

```
[root@server ~]# su ks1
[root@server ~]#
```

I did add my user to `wheel` but that didn't affect the result!

**As Mentioned in Comments**

```
[root@server ~]# getent passwd ks1
ks1:x:1004:1006::/home/ks1:/bin/false
```

Do you what the problem is?

Comment: does the target user have a valid shell? `getent passwd ksl` (or `ks1`, I can't tell from the graphic)

Comment: Please do not paste screenshots but rather copy text from terminal

Comment: `ks1` does not have a valid shell. There shell is `/bin/false` @Jeff add that as an answer. You need to set there shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to `s`witch `u`ser to another user, you need a shell. The shell for `su` is specified in the following order:

- the shell specified with --shell
- The shell specified in the environment variable SHELL if the --preserve-environment option is used.
- the shell listed in the passwd entry of the target user
- /bin/sh

Since you did not specify a `--shell` or `--preserve-environment` option, and the user had a shell listed, `su` executed that shell, which immediately exited.

Try, instead, setting a valid shell on the user, or specifying a shell with `--shell`.

```
su --shell /bin/bash ks1
# or
chsh -s /bin/bash ks1
su ks1
```

Comment: That was the problem. I'm newbie, thanks for your help